# Localstorage is cleared when i'm doing this.router.navigate

Tags: angular, typescript, session, angular-ui-router

I'm developing a website with Angular 5 + Typescript. 
I use the localStorage to store the JWT Token for the login.

When i'm clicking in a link ( Home or another ) , I use a function like this one :

```
public toHome() {
    this.router.navigate(['']);
}
```

After clicking on the link, my localStorage and my sessionStorage is cleared and so my user is disconnected.

Who can help me please ? 
thanks you

Comment: The question lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Nothing in the question explains how storages can be cleared.

Comment: Storages don't need to be cleared. This is why i'm asking why the storage is cleared after after route navigate

Comment: Show some more code? Angular Router definately does not touch local- or sessionstorage, so you must be accidentally clearing or setting the token to null somewhere. In a Route Guard perhaps?

Comment: Or are you properly setting it in the first place? Did you check the token exists in storage, at chrome dev tools > application after logging in the user?

Comment: There's nothing in router that involves storages.  Currently you're the only person who can answer that because nobody else saw the app. MCVE is a requirement for code-related questions, otherwise the question is considered off-topic and can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

dont use routing in html file, instead you can use Router function while form submition in component.ts file as like :- 
this.router.navigate(['/path']);

and dont forget to import Router file and include it in constructor.